# Is every extreme probability on a countably generated space a point mass?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

An *extreme* probability $P$ on the measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal A)$ is such that $P(A) \in \{0,1\}$ for every $A \in \mathcal A$. $P$ is a *point mass* if there is some $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $P(A) = 1_A(\omega)$ for every $A \in \mathcal A$. Clearly every point mass is extreme.

Earlier today I was wondering whether every extreme probability is a point mass. I think I convinced myself that this is not the case by considering $\mathcal A =$ the countable/co-countable sigma-algebra over some uncountable set $\Omega$. Then, $P(A)=1$ for every co-countable $A$ defines an extreme probability that cannot be a point mass.

> I am now wondering if the result holds when $\mathcal A$ is countably generated. I think the answer is yes, but would appreciate verification of this proof.

Let $\mathcal A$ be countably generated by $A_1,A_2,...$. Consider sets of the form $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty B_i$, where each $B_i =$ either $A_i$ or $A_i^c$. These sets are disjoint, in $\mathcal A$, and they are *atoms* of $\mathcal A$ in the sense that $\mathcal A$ does not contain any strict subsets of these sets. If $P$ is extreme, then it assigns exactly one of these atoms, call it $A^*$, probability $1$. In particular, $A^*$ is that atom where $B_i = A_i$ iff $P(A_i)=1$. Then, for any $\omega \in A^*$, $P(A) = 1_A(\omega)$ for all $A \in \mathcal A$.